# Error when running unit test "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-testing-library, react-typescript, react-test-renderer

I have a unit test here and I am performing a click event. I am getting the error:
`Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

```
describe("when the menu icon has been clicked", () => {
    test("the account menu should be displayed", () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<AccountMenu userDetails={fakeUser}></AccountMenu>);
        const button = getByTestId("button-icon-element");
        fireEvent.click(button);
        screen.debug();
    });
});
```

I am pretty sure I know why it's crying but wondering if there is a simple way to get around this whilst unit testing.
The unit testing frame work I'm using is `@testing-libary/react`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are required to wrap any elements being tested in a BrowserRouter.

```
const { getByTestId } = render(<BrowserRouter><AccountMenu userDetails={fakeUser}></AccountMenu></BrowserRouter>);
```

And then it can be clicked.

Comment: don't forgot to import ```import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Wrapper Component to work with BrowserRouter

```
const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
       {children}
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

const renderWithRouter = (ui) => {
  return render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper});
};
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
const { getByTestId } = renderWithRouter(<AccountMenu userDetails={fakeUser} />)
```

Comment: Ahh okay that's cool. Little cleaner too.